# How to extract a URL from a 200 character string of words in C#, preferably using RegExp

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex, string

I'd like to implement a RegExp (regular expression) that can check a string to see if it contains "http://" (i.e. it contains a URL), and then take that whole URL into a new string variable. The string I am using is not HTML, it is simply text with any arrangement of words, characters, numbers and URLs.

I'd imagine I'd look for a mention of "http://" within my string, and take a new string whose starting point is http:// and the end of the string is the next whitespace point just after the full URL.

PLEASE HELP, I've looked high and low for this to no avail!

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Need an example, and what can be used to know the end of the url vs the rest of whatever text there is.  Good resource btw: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Ok take your average Twitter post. That's the text I'm dealing with (less than 200 character string actually). The JSON formatted info from Twitter contains non-HTML nested URLs within the text message body itself.

I would love to know how to write or even READ a simple RegEx but I really struggle with it I'm afraid :S

Comment: Time to learn - the website I gave is excellent at stepping through regex construction, and it lists software you can use to test regexes before you implement them in code.  I use RegexCoach myself.

Comment: A fair point if ever there was one... Hmmmm.. Metacharacters! 

Still, if anyone can help, please do. I think RegEx is my only option here especially as I know just how much more efficient they are compared with using String methods (I used to do Perl ;)

Comment: Then you might be disappointed.  The entire PERL language and runtime system are optimized around making regexp fast, since that's the primary use case.  In .NET you're likely going to need some effort to make regexes perform well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've being answering to smth like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694825/find-a-specific-word-in-a-website-using-asp-net-c/1694934#1694934). I guess that code could be changed to suit your needs; it loads text file and searched for urls.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("c:\\test.txt")))
{
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    string pattern = @"((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)";
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(content, pattern);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' repeated at position {1}",
                          groups[0].Value, groups[0].Index);
    }
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: thanks a lot, looks good, i will try it tomorrow and let you know :)

Comment: I adapted this a bit but the RegEx part is PERFECT for extracting any Internet address from a string.

Thanks!!